# How to get the number of ticks from a timer

Tags: c#, timer, tostring

I'm building a very basic program where a whenever a timer ticks a button moves around the screen, chasing a button controlled by you. I have a textbox which i would like to use to display the number of times the timer ticks, but have no idea how to do that.

My Code looks something like:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds=0;
        seconds++;
textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(seconds);
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: you should put ur int seconds defination out of this timer1_tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you have to declare your seconds globally like

```
int seconds=0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds++;
    textBox2.Text = seconds.ToString();
```

Because your current code is declaring `seconds` variable everytime it hits the event and thus it would be always `1` instead of increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your  `seconds` variable needs to be local to the class not local to the function. Currently every tick you create a new variable and set it to 0, you need to just create it once.

```
private int seconds=0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   seconds++;
   textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(seconds);
```